# How can I convert this CSV to JSON with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to convert a CSV file to JSON using Ruby. I am very, very, green when it comes to working with Ruby (or any language for that matter) so the answers may need to be dumbed down for me. Putting it in JSON seems like the most reasonable solution to me because I understand how to work with JSON when assigning variables equal to the attributes that come in the response. If there is a better way to do it, feel free to teach me.

My CSV is in the following format:

```
Header1,Header,Header3
ValueX,ValueY,ValueZ
```

I would like to be able to use the data to say something along the lines of this:

For each ValueX in Row 1 after the headers, check if valueZ is > ValueY. If yes, do this, if no do that. I understand how to do the if statement, just now how to parse out my information into variables/arrays.

Any ideas here?

Comment: `str.split(',')` produces an array of the comma-separated fields, and `str.to_i` or `str.to_f` convert to integer and float, respectively. If you can do the if and the assignments, this should get you there.

Comment: @Arkku: CSV cannot in general be parsed by `split(',')`; for example, `Bogart,"Here's looking at you, kid"` would give you three fields instead of the correct two.

Comment: @Amadan Yes, true, I kind of assumed that the data looks like the OP's example and this is a simple one-use program for that data, but of course the question does not actually include this information, so the more general CSV parser is better if this is for a "real program". =)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's important that you show us what you've tried. We can help you fix your code, but if we write it with no idea what your code looks like then we'll generate something that has no resemblance to yours making it likely you'll have errors when you shoehorn it into place. Converting CSV to JSON isn't too hard but you can easily run into scalability problems because CSV files can be huge.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'
rows = []
CSV.foreach('a.csv', headers: true, converters: :all) do |row|
  rows << row.to_hash
end
puts rows.to_json
# => [{"Header1":"ValueX","Header":"ValueY","Header3":"ValueZ"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first pointer:

```
require 'csv'
data = CSV.read('your_file.csv', { :col_sep => ',' }
```

Now you should have the data in `data`; you can test in irb.

I don't entirely understand the question:

```
if z > y
  # do this
else
  # do that
end
```

For JSON, you should be able to do `JSON.parse()`.

I am not sure what target format JSON requires, probably a Hash.

You can populate your hash with the dataset from the CVS:

```
hash = Hash.new
hash[key_goes_here] = value_here
```